# How to remove array in this situation?

Tags: php

I have the following:

```
array(
    array(
    [Title] => Bsapwut cljxte qee poaof aazait
    [Section] => videos
    [Category1] => teste
    [Category2] => teste2
    ),
    array(
    [Title] => Bsapwut cljxte qee poaof aazait
    [Section] => articles
    [Category1] => teste
    [Category2] => teste2
    ),
    array(
    [Title] => Bsapwut cljxte qee poaof aazait
    [Section] => videos
    [Category1] => teste
    [Category2] => teste2
    )
);
```

Notice that in the second array the item "section" receives "articles". I need that all arrays that contain section, and that in turn receive "articles", be removed from the parent array. All other arrays that have "section" as "videos" must be kept.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(
        array(
            'Title' => 'Bsapwut cljxte qee poaof aazait',
            'Section' => 'videos',
            'Category1' => 'teste',
            'Category2' => 'teste2',
        ),
        array(
            'Title' => 'Bsapwut cljxte qee poaof aazait',
            'Section' => 'articles',
            'Category1' => 'teste',
            'Category2' => 'teste2',
        ),
            array(
            'Title' => 'Bsapwut cljxte qee poaof aazait',
            'Section' => 'videos',
            'Category1' => 'teste',
            'Category2' => 'teste2',
        )
    );
```

> Method 1. Using Array Filter

```
$filteredArr = array_filter($arr, function ($inArr) {
    return ( array_key_exists('Section', $inArr) && $inArr['Section'] == 'videos' );
});
echo "<pre>";
print_r($filteredArr);
```

> Method 2. Foreach and `Unset()`

```
foreach ($arr as $index => $inArr) {
    if (!empty($inArr['Section']) && $inArr['Section'] == 'articles') {
        unset($arr[$index]);
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
```